# Flutter says Dart version is 2.13.4 even though it's 2.16.0

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to install this [http package](https://pub.dev/packages/http) to my flutter app.

But when i perform `flutter pub get` I get this error:

```
The current Dart SDK version is 2.13.4.

Because http 0.13.4 requires SDK version >=2.14.0 <3.0.0 and no versions of http match >0.13.4 <0.14.0, http ^0.13.4 is forbidden.
So, because app depends on http ^0.13.4, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because spotlight depends on http ^0.13.4, version solving failed.)
```

However I performed `flutter upgrade` before this and it says i'm on the latest version which includes Dart.

```
Flutter is already up to date on channel master
Flutter 2.9.0-1.0.pre.198 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 3f775d864e (11 hours ago) • 2021-12-26 08:59:07 -0500
Engine • revision d56b72b117
Tools • Dart 2.16.0 (build 2.16.0-135.0.dev) • DevTools 2.9.2
```

Why is this?

Edit: `pubspec.yaml` below:

```
name: app
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  http: ^0.13.4

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

In my settings it says `2.13.4`:

[image]

EDIT: So the problem is the Flutter path is incorrect when I type `which flutter`. It is different from my path in Android Studio. How can I change this?

Comment: You haven't shown your `pubspec.yaml` file.  Does it specify a minimum Dart SDK version of 2.14.0 or higher?

Comment: Would you mind sharing your pubspec.yaml?

Comment: Hi both I have shared my `pubspec.yaml` in the edit. Changing the environment sdk to `sdk: ">=2.14.0 <3.0.0"`still returns the same error after running `pub get`.

Comment: Just checked my settings under Languages & Frameworks and it says `2.13.4` - added screenshot in edit

Answer (score 3):

Solved: The problem is that the flutter path being used in the terminal of Android Studio was different to the flutter path in `Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > Flutter`. I found this out by typing in the `which flutter` command, which pointed to a different flutter path.

Answer (score 1):

Look for the sdk setting in your project's `pubspec.yaml` file. This is what determines the minimum Dart SDK version for you project. Change to lower bound to 2.14.0.

```dart
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.14.0 <3.0.0"
```

Comment: I did this, then ran `pub get` but still returned the same error.

Comment: Just checked my settings under Languages & Frameworks and it says `2.13.4` - added screenshot in edit

Comment: @Zorgan Restart your IDE and make sure the flutter executable you added to your path is the same as what you see in your screenshot.

Comment: I have restarted the IDE and the path is correct. Flutter path: `/Users/jameskrousorati/Documents/flutter` & Dart path is: `/Users/jameskrousorati/Documents/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using FVM, make sure you point the Flutter SDK path to the symbolic link folder in your project, that then references the latest active Flutter sdk version

Something like:
C:\Dev\Flutter\TestFlutter\**.fvm\flutter_sdk**

This is critical for it to work!

Answer (score 0):

First thing I can imagine is the following.

Check Flutter and Dart settings in Settings -> Language & Frameworks -> Flutter / Dart

Make sure you use the proper flutter version and dart sdk comes from flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk

For example my flutter is in C:\flutter and the dart-sdk's path is C:\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk

Comment: Yes the dark sdk comes from `/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk` - however if you check my edit it shows a screenshot with an old version that can't be upgraded

Answer (score 0):

[image]

check the current path of dart SDK in vscode